# call google app script htmlservice.createTemplateFromFile(file) with file located on sub folder

Tags: google-apps-script

On a side bar google app script `htmlservice.createTemplateFromFile(file)` is used to launch the side bar by user request.

When the html `file` (the client html file) is located on the root folder, all works smoothly.

I want to rearrange the project files into several subfolders.
I'm using *visual studio code* and `clasp push` to push changes to server.

Everything is ok, except with the `file` location.
When moving the `file`, I can not find the way to supply the right path.

for example:
before rearrange two files (and others) were on the google editor.

- client.html
- server.gs

after moving to subfolder and pushing to server, as the editor does not support sub folders it is reflected with the files names so:

- ./subFolder/client.html
- ./subFolder/sever.gs

I also moved the server js (gs in google editor) to the same folder

Code in server to launch side bar

```
function launchSideBar(){    
    //try obvious
    let file = "client"; // #1
    file = "./client"; // #2
    
    //like it displays in editor
    file = ".subFolder/client"; // #3
    
    /*maybe server is launched from root, 
      although it also resides on sun folder, so supply 
      relative path from root, like for other files (css,ims etc)
    */
    file = "./subFolder/client"; // #4

    let output = 
        HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile(file);

    //launch
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi() 
      .showSidebar(output);
    
}
```

you can see the 4 options I have tried (of course only one different option **was not** commented each time)

When trying to display the side bar from the sheet added menu item, there is an error message

```
Exception: No HTML file named subFolder/client was found.
```

each time file name is different of course.

server is recognized automatically although also moved.

Ideas?

Comment: Try `subFolder/client` instead.

Comment: @TheAddonDepot I'm loosing my creativity if I didn't see this before. If you'll answer, I will mark it the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `file = "subFolder/client"` instead.